# sed: replace pattern using a list of variables only once

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I am new to sed and would like to know how to replace a pattern with a different variable every time

I have a txt file that looks like this:

```
@K3KFV:1:1109:11598:25872
@K3KFV:1:2101:22577:15247
@K3KFV:1:1110:13477:13178
@K3KFV:1:2113:23585:6859... (etc)
```

In total there are 200 different lines. In addition I have another file:

```
ASF356_KB822565.1:1065516-1065795
TAGGTCAAGCCCTCGGTCTATTAGTATTGGTCAGCTTAATACATTGCTGCACTTACACCT
CCAACCTATCTACCTTGTTGTCTTCAAGGGACCTTACTCACTTGCGTTTTGGGATATCTT
 
ASF356_KB822565.1:1065796-1066075
CGGATAGGGACCGAACTGTCTCACGACGTTCTGAACCCAGCTCGCGTACCGCTTTAATGG
GCGAACAGCCCAACCCTTGGGACCTACTTCAGCCCCAGGATGCGATGAGCCGACATCGAG
 
ASF356_KB822565.1:1066076-1066355
CCTTTTGCCTTTACACTCTTTGAATGGTTTCCAATCATTCTGAGGTGACCTTCGAGCGCC
TCCGTTACTCTTTTGGAGGCGACCGCCCCAGTCAAACTGCCCGCCTGACATTGTCCTTCA
```

which also contains 200 instances of "ASF....."

What I want is to replace the line containing "ASF..." with one from "@K3KFV:....." so in the end it will look like:

```
@K3KFV:1:1109:11598:25872
TAGGTCAAGCCCTCGGTCTATTAGTATTGGTCAGCTTAATACATTGCTGCACTTACACCT
CCAACCTATCTACCTTGTTGTCTTCAAGGGACCTTACTCACTTGCGTTTTGGGATATCTT

@K3KFV:1:2101:22577:15247
CGGATAGGGACCGAACTGTCTCACGACGTTCTGAACCCAGCTCGCGTACCGCTTTAATGG
GCGAACAGCCCAACCCTTGGGACCTACTTCAGCCCCAGGATGCGATGAGCCGACATCGAG

@K3KFV:1:1110:13477:13178
CCTTTTGCCTTTACACTCTTTGAATGGTTTCCAATCATTCTGAGGTGACCTTCGAGCGCC
TCCGTTACTCTTTTGGAGGCGACCGCCCCAGTCAAACTGCCCGCCTGACATTGTCCTTCA
```

This is the shell script I have so far:

```
input="K3KFVfile.txt"

while IFS= read -r title
do
        sed '/ASF/c'$title'' ASF_file
done < "$input"
```

But instead of giving me 200 lines of @K3KFV... I get 40000 because each ASF line gets replaced with every single one of the @K3KFV lines.

Is there a way to use sed to replace a pattern using a variable only once before moving on? Is sed the correct command to use in this case?

Comment: I added the blank lines because of formatting. Thanks for the suggestion I'll edit it for clarification.

Comment: Thanks! much clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the GNU implementation of sed, you could use the (uppercase) `R` command - one of its [Commands Specific to GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-Commands) - to read and insert a single line of the first file each time it matches a line starting with `ASF` in the second. Then delete the matched line:

```
$ sed '/^ASF/{
R K3KFVfile.txt
d
}' ASF_file
@K3KFV:1:1109:11598:25872
TAGGTCAAGCCCTCGGTCTATTAGTATTGGTCAGCTTAATACATTGCTGCACTTACACCT
CCAACCTATCTACCTTGTTGTCTTCAAGGGACCTTACTCACTTGCGTTTTGGGATATCTT

@K3KFV:1:2101:22577:15247
CGGATAGGGACCGAACTGTCTCACGACGTTCTGAACCCAGCTCGCGTACCGCTTTAATGG
GCGAACAGCCCAACCCTTGGGACCTACTTCAGCCCCAGGATGCGATGAGCCGACATCGAG

@K3KFV:1:1110:13477:13178
CCTTTTGCCTTTACACTCTTTGAATGGTTTCCAATCATTCTGAGGTGACCTTCGAGCGCC
TCCGTTACTCTTTTGGAGGCGACCGCCCCAGTCAAACTGCCCGCCTGACATTGTCCTTCA
```

You can write it as a one-liner if you prefer:

```
sed -e '/^ASF/{R K3KFVfile.txt' -e 'd}' ASF_file
```

---

Alternatively you could consider using awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{K[FNR] = $0; next} /^ASF/{$0 = K[++n]} 1' K3KFVfile.txt ASF_file
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a bit of a riff on [@steeldriver's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/694673/4667)

If the blank lines in the ASF_file are truly empty (no whitespace), then this awk would work

```bsh
awk '
    NR == FNR {x[FNR] = $0; next}
    {$1 = x[FNR]; print}
' K3KFVfile.txt RS='' ORS='\n\n' FS='\n' OFS='\n' ASF_file
```

Before it starts reading the 2nd file, I'm changing some awk variables to control how the records and fields are determined. I'm usually not a fan of this style, but it works well here. This GNU awk version is a little tidier

```bsh
gawk '
    NR == FNR {x[FNR] = $0; next}
    ENDFILE {RS = ""; ORS = "\n\n"; FS = OFS = "\n"}
    {$1 = x[FNR]; print}
' K3KFVfile.txt ASF_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` :

```bsh
awk '/^ASF/ {getline < "@K3FVfile.txt"};1' ASF_file
```

---

Same thing in `Perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/^ASF.*/<STDIN>/se' ASF_file < @K3FVfile.txt
```

---

Using POSIXly sed:

```bsh
sed -n '/\n/bh
  1{
    :k3
      H;1h;n
    /^@K3KFV/bk3
  }
  /^ASF/g
  P;/\n.*\n/D
  s/.*\n//;th
  d;:h
  h
' @K3FVfile.txt ASF_file
```

---

Using list comprehension in Python:

```bsh
python3 -c 'import sys;a,b = sys.argv[1:]
with open(a) as f, open (b) as g:
  print(*[next(f) if l.startswith("ASF") else l for l in g],sep="",end="")
' @K3FVfile.txt ASF_file
```

---

Output :

```
@K3KFV:1:1109:11598:25872
TAGGTCAAGCCCTCGGTCTATTAGTATTGGTCAGCTTAATACATTGCTGCACTTACACCT
CCAACCTATCTACCTTGTTGTCTTCAAGGGACCTTACTCACTTGCGTTTTGGGATATCTT
 
@K3KFV:1:2101:22577:15247
CGGATAGGGACCGAACTGTCTCACGACGTTCTGAACCCAGCTCGCGTACCGCTTTAATGG
GCGAACAGCCCAACCCTTGGGACCTACTTCAGCCCCAGGATGCGATGAGCCGACATCGAG
 
@K3KFV:1:1110:13477:13178/
CCTTTTGCCTTTACACTCTTTGAATGGTTTCCAATCATTCTGAGGTGACCTTCGAGCGCC
TCCGTTACTCTTTTGGAGGCGACCGCCCCAGTCAAACTGCCCGCCTGACATTGTCCTTC
```

---